# RSA and possible range of $\phi(n)$

Tags: rsa

If $n = p_1 p_2$ for primes $p_1 \ne p_2$, $\phi(n)$ is $\phi(p_1)\cdot\phi(p_2)$. Does that mean that the possible range of $\phi(n)$ is somewhat narrow, that $(p_1-1) \cdot (p_2-1)$ (that is, $\phi(n)$) is close to $p_1\cdot p_2$ (that is, $n$)?

Answer (score 4):

$n - \phi(n) = p + q - 1$.  $p$ and $q$ are secret uniform random 1024-bit prime numbers.  Is a difference of near $2^{1024}$ ‘close’?

Comment: what I mean is, phi(n) should be much much closer to n than to 0?

Comment: Well, what's your metric and what do you consider close?  The absolute distance from $\phi(n)$to $n$ is $p + q - 1 \approx 2^{1024}$; of course, $n$ and $\phi(n)$ are near $2^{2048}$, so, in that sense, yes, $\phi(n)$ is closer to $n$ than to $0$.

Comment: largest difference would be if either prime is 2 then I guess

Comment: If either prime is 2, then you are in trouble for RSA!

Comment: yes but, like, I mean, largest difference would be if either prime is as small as possible? or, what you said is exactly that, so if 2 does not work would you not have to adjust the range you gave?

Comment: or you said near 2^1024. as I am learning RSA, have just recently understood it (learnt the steps a year ago but now understand why it works), what would be the lower range of either prime, if 2 is not good? 3, or, 11, or, around where?

Comment: Well, sure, in principle, for distinct primes the smallest distance from $\phi(n)$ to $n$ is $4 = 2 + 3 - 1$, in which case $n = 6$ and $\phi(n) = 2$ is closer to $0$ than to $n$.  The trouble comment was about getting any security out of the system.

Comment: For security, you choose $p$ and $q$ to be, say, between $2^{1023}$ and $2^{1024}$.

Comment: I assumed 1024 bit primes, or similar size

Comment: if p and q are between 2^1023  and 2^1024, would that not place phi(n) close to n?

Comment: It comes back to what your definition of close is.  Yes, $2^{1024} \approx n - \phi(n) \ll \phi(n) \approx 2^{2048}$.  One side is smaller than the other, but they're all very large numbers!

Comment: how do you get n - phi(n) = p+q-1?

Comment: Expand $(p - 1) (q - 1)$.

Comment: right, was halfway to it, thanks

Comment: tested with a few numbers. the distance is the primes added together like you said, close to bit size for primes